# How do you update what you're working on while developing in angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

When I use angular CLI and do `ng serve` I am able to make changes and able to instantly see them on the web browser. However, I am using the MEAN stack and unable to use ng serve. How would I go about having the same functionality as `ng serve` using the MEAN stack?

Comment: can you use webpack?

Comment: I think you can use `ng` features with the MEAN stack. Why can't you use it?

Comment: oh I guess you can.. haha